# Cant run my app on my iOS devices after upgrading to Yosemite and iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode

xcode wont let me run my app on my iOS devices - it says I have the wrong OS on them.  I just upgraded my mac to Yosemite and my iOS devices to iOS 8.1.

I had no problems before I upgraded.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your old devices still on the Gold Master version of iOS 8.1?

Comment: That was the exact error message? Consider adding the exact error message to the question.

Comment: Thank you both for the help.  The problem was that I needed to upgrade xcode v6.01 to the latest version (v6.1) and when I did that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that you are not using Xcode 6.1. The same thing happened to me yesterday. Downloaded Xcode 6.1 and everything became fine.

Comment: Yes you are correct - just did that a few moments before you replied and that did it.  Thanks!